# How to create Key & Value in React using Array

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I have a string array & need to create key & value like below....

```
const output = { string1: true, string2: true,  string3: true };
```

Example

```
const strarray  = ["string1","string2","string3"];
```

I need output like

```
const output = { string1: true, string2: true,  string3: true };
```

How to achieve in React-Typescript?

Comment: I can't understand what you want to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `reduce` method to generate object from array of string

```js
const strarray  = ["string1","string2","string3"];

const output = strarray.reduce((c,data)=>{
 c[data] = true;
 return c; 
},{})

console.log(output)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: I am getting Lint Error "error  Arrow function should not return assignment  no-return-assign". Any other syntax?

Comment: I have changed the format @Somashekhar

Comment: This worked. Thanks 
strarray?.reduce<Record<string, boolean>>((acc, currentVal) => {
          acc[currentVal] = true;
          return acc;
        }, {})

Answer (score 1):

I understand the question is  `how can I achieve in react-ts`. so I think it is easy. the above answer was correct but there are some linting errors. I want to suggest like:

```
  type objType = Record<string, boolean>;
  const strarray: string[] = ["string1", "string2", "string3"];
  const output: objType = strarray.reduce((c: objType, data: string) => {
    c[data] = true;
    return c;
  }, {});

  console.log(typeof output);
  console.log(output)
```

hope that can help your listing error. *** cause there are too many edits. I write it as a answer. #credit above answer

[example](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-ioana-xf9f7j?file=/src/App.tsx:58-332)

Comment: This worked. Thanks 
strarray?.reduce<Record<string, boolean>>((acc, currentVal) => {
          acc[currentVal] = true;
          return acc;
        }, {})